# Python selenium script does not open a browser on default display from the crontab

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, xvfb

I would like to open a web page in a browser on raspberry by running a python selenium script every n hours **from the crontab**.

Its a pretty standard script that works if I run it locally on that machine.

So if i connect a keyboard to the raspberry and run

```
python /home/pi/ww/open_dashboard.py >> /home/pi/ww/selenium_output.txt
```

it will open the browser and do the selenium commands that I need.

Now I can also ssh into the raspberry and run

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && python /home/pi/ww/open_dashboard.py >> /home/pi/ww/selenium_output.txt
```

and I can see a browser open and do what I need on the monitor connected to the raspberry.

Now when I add this line to the cron.

```
57 9 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && python /home/pi/ww/open_dashboard.py >> /home/pi/ww/selenium_output.txt
```

I can see that cron executed the command if I check `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

```
Jul 18 09:57:01 raspberrypi CRON[2971]: (pi) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0 && python /home/pi/ww/open_dashboard.py >> /home/pi/ww/selenium_output.txt)
```

But browser did not open on the monitor connected to the raspberry. What could I be doing wrong here? :)

Comment: Crontab has no X11 session associated with it and so will not be able to work with GUIs and open browsers.

Comment: @holdenweb But I want it to access the physical display. I know how to run it headless, but I want it to actually display some dashboards for me.

Comment: The question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027385/using-selenium-on-raspberry-pi-headless is about selenium and this question is about cron and xvfb. I dont have any issues running selenium on raspberry. I have an issue with cron using the default display.